# How to view Oracle Reports 4.5 .RDF file just to see the logic?

Tags: oraclereports

What is the solution to view Oracle 4.5 .RDF (Report Definition File) file(s) just to see the logic?

We are not interested in migrating to Forms 11g and we only need to see the code in order to understand the logic and convert Forms 4.5 to a .NET solution.

Tired using Notepad++ in various ways etc.

Comment: Without more detail, this is difficult to answer.  However, you might find this thread on the Oracle forums: [Comparing Oracle Reports (.rdf files)](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/928841).  Do you already have the RDF files in hand?  There are a number of RDF serialization formats, but they should all be text-based, at varying levels of human-readability.

Comment: I think .RDF by Oracle is proprietary so not going to have much luck in this department..

Comment: If Oracle reports are generally using RDF then it should be a plain text format that you can open in any text editor.  Trying that and posting some example data if it works would be useful

Comment: @RobV RDF for Oracle = `Report Definition File` not `Resource Description Framework`

Comment: Meant to say "genuinely using RDF" as in the [Resource Description Framework](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/)

Comment: Ah, since so many people are using RDF these days to represent information, I assumed (as did @RobV, it appears) that Oracle was, too.  I'll edit to remove the [tag:rdf] tag from the question.  In the future, please be sure to check out the tag descriptions before tagging;  the description for [tag:rdf] is "The Resource Description Framework (RDF) is a language for representing information about resources in the World Wide Web. It is a syntax independent data model that may be serialised in a variety of concrete syntaxes. RDF is the core data format used on the Semantic Web."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the 10g or 11g development tools.  They are free to download and don't incur licensing costs unless you are using them to develop an application with them.  You could even go so far as to install the development tools, convert the files to .xml using rwconverter and then uninstall the tools again and read the .xml source code....